# Problemas con los vacíos al cambiar un dato

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente df

```
   df <- read.table(text = '
         X0 X1 X2 X3 X4
          0  S  NA NA NA
          1  NA  0  1 0
          0  0 NA  0 0 
          1  0  0  0 1
          1  NA NA NA NA
          1  N  NA NA NA
          1  N  0  1 1', header = TRUE)


  X0   X1   X2  X3  X4
1  0    S   NA  NA  NA
2  1    NA   0   1   0
3  0    0   NA   0   0
4  1    0    0   0   1
5  1    NA  NA  NA  NA
6  1    N   NA  NA  NA
7  1    N    0   1   1
```

Quiero que todo lo que tenga N en la columna X1 y vacío en las columnas x2:x4 se convierta en 0 en la columna x0.

Es decir, me tiene que cambiar el 1 por un 0 en la columna x0 fila 6

```
df$X0 = ifelse(df$X1 == "N" & is.na(df$X2) & is.na(df$X3) & is.na(df$X4),0,df$X0 )
```

Y me lo cambia bien, pero resulta que la fila 5 el 1 me lo convierte en NA

```
  X0   X1   X2  X3  X4
1  0    S   NA  NA   NA
2  1    NA   0   1   0
3  0    0   NA   0   0
4  1    0    0   0   1
5  *NA*    NA  NA  NA  NA
6  0    N   NA  NA  NA
7  1    N    0   1   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en el caso de la fila 5 está evaluando un valor `NA` cundo haces `df$X1 == "N"` esto invalida todas las comparaciones, haciendo que el `ifelse()` termine evaluando un `NA` y el retorno siempre será `NA`, ejemplo:

```
> ifelse(NA, TRUE, FALSE)
[1] NA
```

Tienes que rehacer la condición de esta forma:

```
ifelse((!is.na(df$X1) & df$X1 == "N")  & is.na(df$X2) & is.na(df$X3) & is.na(df$X4),
        0,
        df$X0
)
```